# Python - read from file skip lines starts with #

Tags: python

Try to read file and make a dictionary from lines, skippipng lines starts with # symbol

file example:

```
param1=val1
# here is comment
```

My function:

```
def readFromFile(name):
    config = {}
    with open(name, "r") as f:         
        for line in f.readlines():
            li=line.lstrip()
            if not li.startswith("#"):
                config[line.split('=')[0]] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
    return config
```

I get list index out of range error

But!
if i try to skip lines starts with, for example, symbol "h" - function works well...

Comment: There must be some lines that don't have `=` on them and do not start with `#`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
def readFromFile(name):
    config = {}
    with open(name, "r") as f:         
        for line in f.readlines():
            li = line.lstrip()
            if not li.startswith("#") and '=' in li:
                key, value = line.split('=', 1)
                config[key] = value.strip()
    return config
```

You maybe have a blank line which breaks your split()

Answer (score 4):

Your code works just fine, except for lines that neither start with a `#` nor contain a `=` character. Usually, those are empty lines.

Test for the `=` character before splitting:

```
def readFromFile(name):
    config = {}
    with open(name, "r") as f:         
        for line in f.readlines():
            li=line.lstrip()
            if not li.startswith("#") and '=' in li:
                config[line.split('=')[0]] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
    return config
```

You can simplify the code and make it a dict comprehension:

```
def readFromFile(name):
    with open(name, "r") as f:         
        return {k: v 
            for line in f 
            for (k, v) in (line.strip().split('=', 1),)
            if '=' in line.strip() and line[:1] != '#'}
```

You can loop over `f` (a file object) *directly*; no need to read all lines into memory using `f.readlines()` first. I used `.split('=', 1)` to only split on the equals sign *once*.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a dictionary directly:

```
 def readFromFile(name):
     with open(name) as f:
         return { line.split('=')[0]:line.split('=')[1].strip() for line in f \
                  if not line.startswith('#' and '=' in line }
```

Comment: `return {k:v.strip() for k,v in (line.split('=',1) for line in f if not line.startswith('#') and '=' in line)}`, single split operation.